# Error of calloutException to call class HttpRequest from other class

Tags: apex, callout, httprequest, sync

I'm creating one connection between Sf and Mailchimp. For this, I created a class where is the "HttpRequest" and other class "SyncMailchimp" that calls it  but I have the next message when I try insert contacts from SF in mailchimp

> You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

Below is the code that I used.

Class of connection

```
public with sharing class ConnectionMailchimp{

public String dataMap {get; set;}
public String status {get; set;}
public void connectionMailchimp(String objectList, String secret, String endPoint, String user, String valueMethod, String name){

    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setMethod(valueMethod);
    request.setEndpoint(endPoint);
    request.setHeader('Authorization', user + ' ' + secret);
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.setBody(objectList);

    Http http = new Http();
    request.setTimeout(120000);
    HttpResponse res = http.send(request);
    status = res.getStatus();

    Map<String, Object> responseMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
    dataMap = String.valueOf(responseMap.get('id'));
    }
}
```

Class for sync data in mailchimp

```
public with sharing class SyncMailchimp {
public String secret;
public String endPoint;
public String user;
public List<CampaignMember> listCampaingMembers;
public Integer numberMembers {get;set;}
public ConnectionMailchimp connection;
public String jsonListCamping = '';
public String valueMethod;

ApexPages.StandardController con;

public SyncMailchimp(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    con = controller;
    listCampaingMembers = [SELECT ContactId, LeadId, Contact.Email, Contact.Firstname, Contact.LastName,
                            Contact.Name, Contact.Phone, Contact.HasOptedOutOfEmail, Lead.Email, Lead.Name, 
                            Lead.Phone, campaign.List_Id__c, campaign.List_Id_MC__c, Campaign.Id FROM CampaignMember WHERE CampaignId = :con.getId()];

    numberMembers = listCampaingMembers.size();

    Connection_Mailchimp__c cl = [SELECT Endpoint__c, Secret__c, User__c FROM Connection_Mailchimp__c LIMIT 1];
        secret = cl.Secret__c;
        endPoint = cl.Endpoint__c;
        user = cl.User__c;

}

public void createCampaing(){
    connection = new ConnectionMailchimp();
    for(CampaignMember c : listCampaingMembers){
        Map<String, Object> listmailchimp = new Map<String, Object>();
        Map<String, Object> listmailchimpMerge = new Map<String, Object>();
        String status;

        String idList = c.campaign.List_Id_MC__c;

        if(c.Contact.HasOptedOutOfEmail == false){
            status = 'subscribed';
        }
        else{
            status = 'unsubscribed';
        }
        if(c.ContactId != null){
            listmailchimp.put('email_address', c.Contact.Email);
            listmailchimp.put('status', status);
            listmailchimpMerge.put('FNAME', c.Contact.Firstname);
            listmailchimpMerge.put('LNAME', c.Contact.LastName);
            listmailchimp.put('merge_fields', listmailchimpMerge);
        }

        if(c.LeadId != null){
            listmailchimp.put('email_address', c.lead.Email);
            listmailchimp.put('status', status);
            listmailchimpMerge.put('FNAME', c.Lead.Firstname);
            listmailchimpMerge.put('LNAME', c.Lead.LastName);
            listmailchimp.put('merge_fields', listmailchimpMerge);
        }

        jsonListCamping = JSON.serialize(listmailchimp);
        system.debug(jsonListCamping);

        valueMethod = 'POST';
        String nameClass = 'SyncMailchimp';
        String endPointR = endPoint + idList + '/members';
        System.debug(endPointR);
        connection.ConnectionMailchimp(jsonListCamping, secret, endPointR, user, valueMethod, nameClass);
        updateCampaign();
    }
}

public void updateCampaign(){
    for(CampaignMember c : listCampaingMembers){
        Campaign cam = new Campaign();

        if(connection.status == 'OK'){
            cam.Id = c.Campaign.Id;
            cam.Last_Update__c = System.Now();
            cam.Status_Sync__c = connection.status;
        }else{
            cam.Id = c.Campaign.Id;
            cam.Last_Update__c = null;
            cam.Status_Sync__c = connection.status;
        }

        update c;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Could be as simple as moving `updateCampaign();` above the `connection.ConnectionMailchimp(...`, and your doing a lot of this inside your actual for loop, that is dangerous.  Overall some refactoring should happen

Comment: You're also not handling your response correct, you may want to post that also

Answer (score 4):

You can't have this functionality in a loop, because *all* DML must follow *all* callouts:

```
for (CampaignMember member : members)
{
    // callout
    // dml
}
```

You shouldn't have *either* of these operations within a loop anyway. If your endpoint is bulkified, find a way to send the data in bulk, but at the very least you should modify your approach to:

```
for (CampaignMember member : members)
{
    // callout
}
for (CampaignMember member : members)
{
    // set fields only, DO NOT UPDATE HERE
}
update members;
```

Now, as for the callouts, I have no idea what the endpoint accepts, but typically, you would be able to replace `Map<String, Object>` with `List<Map<String, Object>>` and pass that.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> data = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
for (CampaignMember member : members)
{
    data.add(new Map<String, Object>(...));
}
String payload = JSON.serialize(data);
// pass this payload to the callout method now and make just one callout
```

Comment: Hi Adrian, Erika says thank you! She can't comment yet. And the endpoint isn't bulkified, so she needs to make the callout inside the loop. She's actually changing it now to a batch to avoid hitting the 100 callouts limit.

Comment: @Jose she was hitting the limit because she had it in a for loop

Comment: @EricSSH she was actually only making 1 callout, because after the first she was making the dml and the second callout was causing the error. She needs to implement it as a batch because she needs to make N number of callouts.

Comment: A quick correction, in my first comment I stated that the endpoint isn't bulkified and this is wrong. [Mailchimp batch operations](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/batches/) are the bulkify approach, is just a little more complex to implement.